# How to configure less to read non-displayed data into a buffer?

Tags: background-process, less

I recently discovered that you can start and immediately background long-running source code searches piped to less:

`grep -r something | less &`

is there a way to direct `less` to read more of the output into memory than it's currently displaying "in the background" so that when I decide to look at the results of my search I don't need to wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, if you pipe commands, the `bash` shell uses the [pipe(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pipe) libc call to weave the file descriptors of the child tasks. Its default internal buffer size is only 64K.

However, there is a tool

```
buffer
```

for the task, included into most distros. By default, it uses 1MB buffer, but you can increase it to any big. For example

```
grep ..anything, anywhere.. | buffer -m $[1<<30] | less &
```

will be likely enough. :-) It has many other nice features (for example, it can work like a `dd`, or it can print hashes to the stderr after n-byte chunks), it is a... *killer app*. :-)